# How to embed a custom header in packets that are sent by iperf command?

Tags: iperf, iperf3

I am an iperf newbie. I want add custom header with minimal data in the packets that are sent by iperf tool. Is it even possible? If yes, can someone please enlighten me :)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do this from the command line with [iperf 2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf2/). (I can't speak for iperf 3.) Iperf 2 already has its own "protocol" carried in [fields in they payload](https://sourceforge.net/p/iperf2/code/ci/master/tree/include/payloads.h) and a custom header would likely break things. What exactly do you need a custom header for?

Bob